# FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON not working when showing an alert dialog on wear os

Tags: wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I am developing an Wear OS App, that requires to have the screen always on for certain tasks.

To achieve that, I use `window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

It is working fine, but when I show an Dialog, the screen turns off after a few seconds.

I do not want to increase the timeout , but instead I need to keep the screen on while the dialog is showing on the screen.

I tried to use `android:keepScreenOn="true"` on my activity and it's working fine until I show Dialog.

There is how I create dialog.

```
val binding = ProgressLayoutWithTextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
val dialog = Dialog(context)

binding.textProgress.text = message

dialog.setCancelable(false)
dialog.setContentView(binding.root)
dialog.show()
```

I'm using galaxy watch 4 (SM-R880)

Has anyone encountered this problem on a watch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've had this problem.
Solved it by

```
dialog.show()
dialog.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).